# how to retrive base64 string to android from asp.net webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, android-intent, android-networking

## I need to receive base64 string to android application but i got the string from webservice ,

**Server Side

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string IMAGE(string ID)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.in;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;password=");
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdImageSource = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sdImageSource.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table where Ordno=('" + ID + "')", conn);
        DataSet dsImage = new DataSet();
        sdImageSource.Fill(dsImage);

        byte[] blob = (byte[])dsImage.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column_name"];
        string c = Convert.ToBase64String(blob);
        //c = c.Replace(" ", "");
        return c;
    }
```

## Its Returning string properly within string quotes how should i receive at the client or android end , could any one help me with it

**Client Side

*Android main file

```
package com.imageload;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageloadActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Bitmap image; 
     ImageView imageView;
     private Button butt;
     String Str="image",error="0";



        private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IMAGE";
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "IMAGE";
        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

        private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.213/WebSite4/Service.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         this.butt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
          this.imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        this.butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                if(error.equals("0"))
                {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet=true;

                    request.addProperty("ID","1001");                                                                               
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        try
                        {


                            try 
                            {
                                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                            } 
                            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                           

                        ##this is the place wher iam receiving the base64 string but i dont understand why its not retriving the string ? is it Because of its lenth?#SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();



                            SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                            int count=result.getPropertyCount(); 


                            if(count!=1)
                            {
                                String encodedString=result.getProperty(0).toString();

                                 byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
                                 image=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
                                 imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                             }
                            else
                            {
                                String result1  = "Invalid Order Number";
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result1 , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } 
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*output:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
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
</string>
```

** here the problem is i could not receive the whole string on the server sid i am getting an error at "SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();" this place could any one make some comment on it

Comment: How about posting the full error, without that we'll just be playing a guessing game. Thanks.

Comment: D/AndroidRuntime(356): Shutting down VM
: W/dalvikvm(356): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
: E/AndroidRuntime(356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: : java.lang.NullPointerException
: : at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:552)
: : at com.imageload.ImageloadActivity$1.onClick(ImageloadActivity.java:81)
: : at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
: : at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
: E/AndroidRuntime(356): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set ResponseFormat to Json.

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "IMAGE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
public string IMAGE(string ID)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.in;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;password=");
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sdImageSource = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sdImageSource.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table where Ordno=('" + ID + "')", conn);
        DataSet dsImage = new DataSet();
        sdImageSource.Fill(dsImage);

        byte[] blob = (byte[])dsImage.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column_name"];
        string c = Convert.ToBase64String(blob);
        //c = c.Replace(" ", "");
        return c;
    }
```